# Where should I ask my question related to English grammar?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am foreigner and my English is very poor.

But I have to learn English in Stack Exchange.

I have posted a question related to English grammar in English Language & Usage: [Is the Grammar wrong](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597555/is-the-grammar-wrong)

If my article wants correction or critique requests by Stack Exchange, on which Stack Exchange community should I post on?

Comment: Hey! Perhaps you can try asking in [ell.se]. But, your post seems a bit unclear to me.

Comment: In general, "is this correct/find the errors" questions are off-topic on ELL. But if you have something specific about your sentence you're unsure about, you could definitely ask there!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A way for "new users" to ask about their post specifically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274518/282094), here:  https://english.meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Our words are too complicated. Let's make them simpler!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269289/our-words-are-too-complicated-lets-make-them-simpler/269320#269320)* and *[Learning new languages - language translation for foreign SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280488/)*. From the former: *"...competency in the English language is a fundamental requirement for participating in Stack Overflow"*. From the latter: *"Stack Exchange is not [Duolingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duolingo)"*

Comment: To be clear, the (implicit) example used in the *EL&U* question was from [***another*** user's Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521848/) whereas the answer would probably be applied to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74243189/in-pysside2-how-can-i-show-the-thumbnail-for-an-item-in-qtextbrowser-when-the-u). But both Stack Overflow questions are close to being *incomprehensible* (they *could* be the result of [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate) or the equivalent).

Comment: A likely related MSO question: [What are the differences between Stack Overflow in Japanese and Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421244/). Using a different language Stack Overflow as a way out of the problems with English (the profile text includes *"I am interested in Japanese[,] English, [and] even Korean"* (a list of languages seems to be intent))?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to improve your English knowledge, and you have questions about specific aspects of English grammar, vocabulary, pronunciation, usage, etc., then [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) is the place to go.

BUT, it is *off-topic* to simply ask whether your sentence is correct, or ask to find errors, or ask to correct or improve your English writing. Questions like that will be closed. No site on the network accepts that kind of question.

For instance, you asked whether your sentence, "This solution apply my question" had good grammar. That's a request to find errors, so it's off-topic. A better question might be:

> *"This solution apply my question"*
> In that sentence, I'm unsure how to connect "apply" and "my question". Is it just "apply my question", or "apply **with** my question" or something else?

To be clear, the purpose of all questions on ELL is for you and others to *learn English*. If you're ready to work at learning English, and you can ask questions like the above (or better), it's a helpful place.

But if you just want your writing improved and you don't really want to spend the time to improve your English, then this network isn't the place. You probably want a private homework tutor.

Comment: It was *already* [an ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326232/when-hover-on-button-or-when-hovering-on-button) (posted about 4 hours after the EL&U one).

Answer (score 5):

> If my article want to correct or critique requests by Stack Exchange, in which Stack Exchange community should I post about it?

Sorry, but both our English sites here, [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), don't do proofreading for users. You can try to rephrase your questions to ask about grammar questions specifically, e.g., why is the grammar in this sentence so. Also make sure to show your research! As that is one close reason on ELL. Otherwise ELL should be best.

Comment: Lack of research is also a closure reason on ELU.

Comment: It was *already* [an ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326232/when-hover-on-button-or-when-hovering-on-button) (posted about 4 hours after the EL&U one).

Answer (score -1):

Let me address the contents of [your post in English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/597555/) part by part.

> This is my first time to create article. If I get some mistake.
> I hope you will excuse and teach me. The article is written in stackoverflows.

You have frequently mentioned "*article*" in your question. In Stack Exchange, we generally use the word *post*, or to be specific, *question/answer*. Also, you don't need to mention that you're creating a post for the first time as fellow users can identify that on their own.

> [How to show tooltip image when hover on button pyqt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521848/how-to-show-tooltip-image-when-hover-on-button-pyqt5/60522104#60522104)
>
> But the grammar in textbook in Taiwan. After the word "when" will connect V-ing (present progressive).
>
> Hover in the article is after "when". So the word hover will become hovering.
>
> Is the article grammar wrong?

You linked to page in Stack Overflow and asked about the tense of the word "hover", but you didn't mention where the word was exactly mentioned (and the link was a bit confusing). One could only find the word if they searched for it. It's mentioned in the title and in the first sentence of the post.

The title of the post from Stack Overflow is

> How to show tooltip image when **hover** on button pyqt5

and the first sentence:

> I want to show image when **hover** on button.

I suppose you are asking why *hover* is mentioned instead of *hovering* and whether it is appropriate to write like that as per grammar rules.

If you can write your question in a more understandable manner, I think you can post in [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The 1st quote is social/meta content in the main site post & should not be there. Neither does the thanks at the end. The relevant text should be quoted not at a link, posts should be self-contained. If they are only talking about the title, that should be made clear & there is no need to link.

Comment: @philipxy I have added some of your suggestions in my post.

Comment: It was *already* [an ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326232/when-hover-on-button-or-when-hovering-on-button) (posted about 4 hours after the EL&U one).

Comment: "mention that you're creating a post for the first time" The whole paragraph should be gone. Also "the thanks at the end" of the post.